# How to count total results with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, count

Have a problem with total count of ajax searche's results.
There is a mistake "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::total does not exist." if I use directive for example

```
<div class="searched-item">
            <a href="#" class="searched-item-res1">{{ __('main.res_found') }} {{$sfilms->total()}} {{ __('main.res_results') }}</a>
        </div>
```

How to fix it correctly?

blade template:

```
@if($sfilms)
    @if($sfilms->count())
        <div class="searched-item">
            <a href="#" class="searched-item-res1">{{ __('main.res_found') }} {{$sfilms->count()}} {{ __('main.res_results') }}</a>
        </div>
    @else
        <div class="searched-item">
            <a href="#" class="searched-item-res2">{{ __('main.res_found') }} 0 {{ __('main.res_results') }}</a>
        </div>
    @endif
    @foreach($sfilms as $sfilm)
    <div class="search-hits">
        <ol class="search-hits-list">
            <li class="search-hits-item">
                <a href="{{ url('films/'.$sfilm->film_id) }}">
                    <div class="search-img-wrapper"> 
                        @if(!is_null($sfilm->films->poster))
                            <img src="{{$sfilm->films->poster}}" alt="poster" class="news_movies-img">
                        @else
        {{--                <img class="news_movies-img" src="{{ url('/img/no_poster.jpg') }}" alt="poster"/>--}}
                            <img src="{{asset('storage/poster/' . $sfilm->films->id . '.jpg')}}" alt="poster" class="news_movies-img">
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="search-hits-wrapper">
                        <div class="hit-title">
                            <h3>{{ $sfilm->title }}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="hit-title">
                            <h4>{{ $sfilm->films->orig_title }}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <span>
                            <p class="poster_genre-link">{{ $sfilm->films->country}} {{ $sfilm->films->year }}</p>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <p class="poster_genre-link">For age {{ $sfilm->films->age }} +</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    @endforeach
@else
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ __('search_no_results') }}</li>
@endif
```

javascript ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $('#search').keyup(function() {
            var search = $('#search').val();
            if (search == "") {
                $("#memlist").html("");
                $('#result').hide();
            } else {
                $.get("{{ URL::to('/search') }}", {
                    search: search
                }, function(data) {
                    $('#memlist').empty().html(data);
                    $('#result').show();
                })
            }
        });
    });
```

Controller:

```
public function search(Request $request) : View
    {
        $search = $request->input('search');
        $locales = app()->getLocale();

        if ($locales == NULL) {
            $sfilms = Local::where('title_en', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->orWhere('year', 'like', "$search%")->limit(4)->get();
        } else {
            $sfilms = Local::where('title' . '_' . $locales, 'like', "%$search%")
        ->orWhere('year', 'like', "$search%")->limit(4)->get();
        }
  
        return view('layouts.found')->with('sfilms', $sfilms);
    }
```

This works correctly with searched results and I see them, but I don't fix to see exactly count of total results from request.

Comment: The question does not make sense - the code which throws the error is not in your actual Blade code?  The error is very clear - `total()` is not a Collection method.  And in your Blade code you are correctly not using that, you are using `count()`, which should work, and is how you find the number of elements in a Collection.  So what is the problem, why/where are you using `total()`?

Comment: In my other components (for ex. search, tags, result of test) I use total(), which count me all of searched results, not particular page, but all according to my request. In this case, I also want to display everything that is in the request in numerical terms. Not 4 items, which I have limited code, but everything that matches the data entered in the search input. For example, on the syllable "to"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done

Just replace in controller `->limit(4)->get()` to `->paginate(4)`. [According to documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#paginator-instance-methods)

```php
public function search(Request $request) : View
    {
        $search = $request->input('search');
        $locales = app()->getLocale();

        if ($locales == NULL) {
            $sfilms = Local::where('title_en', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->orWhere('year', 'like', "$search%")->paginate(4); 
        } else {
            $sfilms = Local::where('title' . '_' . $locales, 'like', "%$search%")
        ->orWhere('year', 'like', "$search%")->paginate(4);
        }  
  
        return view('layouts.found', ['sfilms'=>$sfilms]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection use the [count()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-count) method to return the total.

So you should be using it like this instead

```php
{{ $sfilms->count() }}
```

Comment: unfortunately dont understand. wrote something like this `$sfilms = Local::where('title_en', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->orWhere('year', 'like', "$search%");
        $collection = collect([$sfilms]);
        $sfilms = $sfilms->limit(4)->get();`

Comment: and in blade `{{$collection->count}}` . But nothing, there is an error "Property [count] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: it's a method so you should write `count()` not `count`